# How to find the closest value in an EXCEL table by referring from the column and return the row value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a below table and i want to find the closest value once i input my number. My answer must return the row value which is **Years of Experiencce** by referring from the two column value below.

#### a) My column 1 value = MYS_02

#### b) My column 2 value = Min Salary

Below are my table:
[image]

This is my formula.

> =INDEX(A3:A15,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($B$2:$K$2&$B$1:$K$1&$B$3:$K$15=$A$18&$A$20&$B$22)*(ROW($B$3:$K$15))))-ROW($B$3)+1)

It works if i input the value that have in the table. However when i input less or more than the value in the table it shows an error

[image]

It also shows wrong ***Years of Experience*** when i insert the value that have duplication in the table. I want my ***Years of Experience*** row shows the closest value.

As you may see when i input **1400** it shows ***Years of Experience*** row of **12**.

[image]

It suppose to show **8** instead of **12**.

So my question is how can i find the closest value.
How can i achieve that?

Comment: What is the correct answer for 1130? What if it was 1177?

Comment: If 1130 it should be 2.. If it 1177 it also also should be 2. It will only hit 3 once it is 1184 > , not more than 1239

Answer (score 1):

to make it short, you can use this formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:A15,MIN(IF(ABS(B3:K15-B22)=MIN(ABS(B3:K15-B22)),ROW(3:15))))
```

> This is an array formula und must be confirmed with Ctrl + Shift + Enter

it checks the whole table to get the closest value (`MIN(ABS(B3:K15-B22))`) and then returns each row (`ROW(3:15)`) with the same difference (`ABS(B3:K15-B22)=`). Then it simply picks the smallest row value (`MIN(IF(...))`) and uses it for the index.

It always goes for the lowes row-number! If B13 and H4 would be the same (and the lowest), it will pick row 4 (and return 1)

**EDIT**:

The correct formula would be:

```
=INDEX(A1:A15,MIN(IF(ABS(IF(B1:K1=A20,IF(B2:K2=A18,B3:K15-B22)))=MIN(ABS(IF(B1:K1=A20,IF(B2:K2=A18,B3:K15-B22)))),ROW(3:15))))
```

> This is an array formula und must be confirmed with Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Does the same like the first formula, but eliminates all columns which do not match the criteria for row 1 and 2 (`IF(B1:K1=A20,IF(B2:K2=A18,B3:K15))`)

**EDIT2**:

Based on comments: If you want to exclude values smaller than the searched value, then pls use this formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:A15,MIN(IF(MAX(IF(B1:K1=A20,IF(B2:K2=A18,IF(B3:K15<=B22,B3:K15))))=IF(B1:K1=A20,IF(B2:K2=A18,IF(B3:K15<=B22,B3:K15))),ROW(3:15))))
```

> This is an array formula und must be confirmed with Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Comment: Hy Dirk. Thanks for your answer.. I want answer first must always check the above two column then find the closest answer. When i check your formula it does not refer to below columns and by this i will show a random value       MYS_02   ,  Min Salary

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that A18 and A20 are selectors. Please see my edited answer and check if that fits your needs ;)

Comment: Dirk, see the Q's comments. The OP doesn't want the MIN(ABS(x-y:y)).; rather the >=.

Answer (score 1):

For the *highest row less than or equal to the proposed salary* put this standard formula in B23.

```
=INDEX(A3:A15, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(1:13)/(B22>=INDEX(B3:J15, , MATCH(A20, B1:J1, 0)+(LEFT(A18, 3)="max"))), 1))
```

If you want the actual salary that is based on, then this standard formula in C22.

```
=INDEX($B$3:$K$15, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(1:13)/(B22>=INDEX(B3:J15, , MATCH(A20, B1:J1, 0)+(LEFT(A18, 3)="max"))), 1), MATCH(A20, B1:K1, 0)+(LEFT(A18, 3)="max"))
```

[image: aggregate_lowest_greater_then]

**Alternate for Absolute Closest**

For the minimum absolute difference between B22 and the appropriate salary column, the years of experience in B23 would be,

```
=INDEX(A3:A15, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:13)/(ABS(B22-INDEX(B3:J15, , MATCH(A20, B1:J1, 0)+(LEFT(A18, 3)="max")))=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ABS(INDEX(B3:K15, 0, MATCH(A20, B1:K1, 0)+(LEFT(A18, 3)="max"))-B22), 1)), 1))
```

The matching table salary would be retrieved with,

```
=INDEX($B$3:$K$15, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:13)/(ABS(B22-INDEX(B3:J15, , MATCH(A20, B1:J1, 0)+(LEFT(A18, 3)="max")))=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ABS(INDEX(B3:K15, 0, MATCH(A20, B1:K1, 0)+(LEFT(A18, 3)="max"))-B22), 1)), 1), MATCH(A20, B1:K1, 0)+(LEFT(A18, 3)="max"))
```

Comment: Hy jeeped thanks for your answet however im using excel 2007...the aggregate function does not supported. Is there any other way to replace the function?